# Running SSIS Package automate failed in SSIS jobs

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Having SSIS package, the flow is Data moves from Hadoop to SQL and from SQL to Postgres. Placed it in GitLab for CI CD. Made the dtsx automate by creating a job in SSIS. When running manually the job got succeeded. In automation the job is failing as Hadoop has no permission from SQL server. In GitLab file taken source as SQL server. Please suggest how to do.

Comment: I think you're using windows authentication to your SQL Server, in this case in your job you need to change the `run as` option, or change your connection string to sql authentication

Comment: It is SQL Server Agent Service Account only.

Comment: So you can add your user by following the documentation, [Configure a User to Create and Manage SQL Server Agent Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/configure-a-user-to-create-and-manage-sql-server-agent-jobs?view=sql-server-ver16), or give  SQL Server Agent Service Account access to your database

Comment: how to give SQL Server Agent Service Account access to your database